# Could you point how to put a button at the right side of the links by using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I'm very new here.

Could you point how to put a functional button at the right side of the links by using jQuery?

[Site's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZNxX.png)

Accordingly to:

```
if(field ==="anexo_v"){
    if(value !==null){
        $(".anexo_v").show();
        var link = "";
        $.each(value,function(id, valor){
            var anexo = valor.anexo;
            anexo = anexo.split("/");
            anexo = $(anexo).get(-1);
            //console.log(valor.anexo);
            link = link+"<p><a href=\'"+valor.anexo+ "\' target=\'_blank\'>"+anexo+"</a></p>";                                             ;
        });
        $("#anexo").html(link);
    }else{
        $(".anexo").hide();
    }
}
```

Plus - this button needs to call, by Ajax, a PHP Codeigniter's controller to perform a deletion (Excluir means deletion).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`link = link+"<p><a href=\'"+valor.anexo+ "\' target=\'_blank\'>"+anexo+"</a></p>";`

to

`link = link+"<p style=\'display:inline\'><a href=\'"+valor.anexo+ "\' target=\'_blank\'>"+anexo+"</a></p><button value=\'Excluir\' onclick=\'functionToMakeAjaxCall("+valor.anexo+")\'></button>";`

and add

```
function functionToMakeAjaxCall(parameter){
    //code to make ajax call to a controller to delete
}
```